# fixltx2e warning! - ShareLaTeX

Tags: warnings, sharelatex, fixltx2e

I'm a using ShareLaTeX to write a report and it is almost perfect in terms of fails and warnings. There is only one warning left, which is the following:

[image: Picture of the warning.]

I have searched online for a solution, but almost all says to remove the usepackage causing the problem. I just simply can find it. It is not in main or preamble, or any of the other document. I use the search function in ShareLaTeX to search for `fixltx2e`, but I find nothing.

Maybe I'm looking for the wrong usepackge, and the mistake might be from another usepackage including `fixltx2e`, but I don't know, which one.

I would really like to fix the warning, as it is the only one left. Anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: It is loaded by some class or another package. You can ignore this warning

Comment: The log file will show you which file is inputting fixltx2e just look at the matching `(...foo.sty...)`

Answer (score 4):

If you use any package like `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}` or any package end with -`fix`, just remove those package and you will no longer get any warning.

Comment: This seems like an arbitrary generalisation that might not always work.

Comment: If you remove `\usepackage{dblfloatfix}`, you won't get a warning, but you also will not get the functionality of that package (in this case, setting a double-column float at the bottom of the page).